# User Login behaviour for MVC model with Propel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, propel

Assume that we have class `User` created by Propel.

What is the correct place for MVC to place method `login()`? This method will implement auditing log interactive with `AuditLog` class.

1. `User::login()`
2. `UserQuery::login()`
3. `UserPeer::login()`
4. `WebController::login()` and `APIController::login()` and `MobileController::login()`
5. `AuditingLog::login()`

Comment: Active record instance is NOT a model.

Answer (score 0):

While lots of people will argue one way or another, in my opinion the act of logging in is not a function of the Model, but business logic that belongs in a Controller. That said, duplicating the functionality across your three controllers isn't really optimal either. My recommendation would be to have a static class outside of the controllers that handles some app logic like that and which each controller calls.